# Java program freezes on calling Thread#join() method

Tags: java

I need to create a program which implements comparing and incrementing two counters in two ways: unsynchronized and synchronized. So I basically have 2 fields int counter & int counter2 and a run() method which simply iterates n times, compares counters, increments counter1, waits 100 ms, and then increments counter2.
I have a working realization, but I need to make main thread finish last and I'm kinda confused about doing it so. The code is:

```
public class Part3 {

    private int counter;    
    private int counter2;

    public synchronized boolean syncEquals() {
        return counter == counter2;
    }

    public synchronized void syncIncrement() {
        counter++;
        try {
            Thread.sleep(100);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        counter2++;
    }


    public static void main(final String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
        Part3 p = new Part3();
        p.compare();
        System.out.println("-----------------------");
        p.compareSync();
    }


    public void compare() throws InterruptedException {
        Thread t1 = new Thread(new Runnable(){
            public void run(){
                for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
                    System.out.println((counter == counter2));
                    counter++;
                    try {
                        Thread.sleep(100);
                    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                    counter2++;
                }
            }
        });

        Thread t2 = new Thread(new Runnable(){
            public void run(){
                for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
                    System.out.println(counter == counter2);
                    counter++;
                    try {
                        Thread.sleep(100);
                    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                    counter2++;
                }
            }
        });

        t1.start();
        t2.start();

        t1.join();
        t2.join();    
    }

    public synchronized void compareSync() throws InterruptedException {
        counter = 0;
        counter2 = 0;
        Thread t1 = new Thread(new Runnable(){
            public void run(){
                for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
                    System.out.println(syncEquals());
                    syncIncrement();
                }
            }
        });

        Thread t2 = new Thread(new Runnable(){
            public void run(){
                for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
                    System.out.println(syncEquals());
                    syncIncrement();
                }
            }
        });

        t1.start();
        t2.start();
    }
}
```

The problem is when I call `t1.join()` and `t2.join()` in `compareSync()` the program freezes and doesn't even print any results of this method. I'm new to threads and would like to know what I'm doing wrong so thank you in advance!

Comment: How do you know it freezes on the join? Which join?

Comment: The problem is the `synchronized void compareSync()` method. It synchronizes on the same object as the `synchronized boolean syncEquals()` and the `synchronized void syncIncrement()` methods. If you call `t1.join(); t2.join();` within the `compareSync()` method  the threads t1 and t2 can never enter the `syncEquals()` method and can never finish. To fix it you need to remove the `synchronized` from the `compareSync()` method.

Comment: I ran it and it didn't freeze for me. It terminated normally. Version: Neon.3 Release (4.6.3)
Build id: 20170314-1500